# VSCode C++: Multiple irrelevant definitions for simple symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, path, editor, multiple-definition-error

For example, in some single `C++` file, the definitions shown for a simple symbol `x` relate to many other irrelevant includePaths: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On2e3.png)

How could this be fixed?

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Comment: @Evg Thanks for that notice and I know that well -- I only use it for personal convenience. What's more, the problem **still exists** even though they're not used: [Screenshot 2][1]. Now the simple local variable `i` doesn't even show up in list.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVr37.png

Comment: That was just a comment, not an answer. Personally, I don't use IntelliSense provided by Microsoft plugin, but prefer [ccls](https://github.com/MaskRay/ccls).

Comment: @Evg Yea... :( I've no idea what's wrong with that. I may try `ccls` if all ways are stuck.